# Что означает знак вопроса в пути к файлу .css и .js?

Tags: javascript, css

`style.css?123123`

`common.js?11133_444`

Что означает знак вопроса? Можно передавать параметры?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Меняя цифры в конце можно заставить браузер думать, что файл новый и, тем самым, заставить его скачать заново, а не использовать кэшированную версию. Используется в случае, когда были внесены изменения в стили и нужно заставить браузеры пользователей затянуть новые стили.

Вместо чисел могут быть буквы - главное, чтобы URL в целом менялся.

Answer (score 6):

Этот прием используется для того, чтобы избегать использование закэшированных таблиц стилей, вместо этого, как было сказано ранее, как только меняются цифры после вопроса, бразуер будет подгружать эту таблицы стилей заново