# Кеширование в IIS и PHP?

Tags: php, кэширование, iis-7

Допустим есть html внутри которого идет такой вывод:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/js/jquery-2.2.0.min.js" ></script>
```

1. Как сказать браузеру, что эти файлы не изменяться до 2030 года? И не нужно даже посылать запросы на сервер по ним.
2. Как сказать браузеру(который стал думать что файлы до 2030 не изменяться) что файлы изменились и нужно их перегрузить заного?
3. Это делается в IIS сервере или в PHP, html можно что то указывать в meta тэгах например?

Comment: Ответ в одной ссылке: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/134503/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BA-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D1%83-css  ...... тоже самое относится к `js`

Comment: @АлексейШиманский 
Это ответ только на пункт 2 из вопроса.